# Does sizeof(function) makes sense?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, language-lawyer, sizeof

I am a bit confused about the `sizeof(function)`. I used to think that `sizeof` operator operates on *class objects, pointers, and references*.

What *operands* can the `sizeof` operator operate?

Does `sizeof(function)` make sense?

Comment: Show an [MCVE]. Did you try `sizeof(function)`? If it means what I guess it should, it won't even compile, because it is not legal C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

> "...`sizeof` cannot be used with function types, incomplete types, or
>   bit-field glvalues"

or from the 2012 Working Draft of the C++ Standard at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf:

> Section 5.3.3 Sizeof
>   "The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function or incomplete type, to an enumeration type whose underlying
>   type is not fixed before all its enumerators have been declared, to
>   the parenthesized name of such types, or to an lvalue that designates
>   a bit-field."

Comment: And a more authoritative reason would quote some C++ standard, like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: Cheers Basile - have added that.

Answer (score 3):

**>  What operands can the sizeof operator operate in C++?**

From the [C++11 ISO Standerds](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)*<sup>(draft N3337, page 105, sec. **5.3.3**)</sup>*

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), 
>   or a parenthesized *type-id*. (Clause 5 <sup><sup>(*draft N3337, page 83*)</sup>))</sup>

---

**>  Does sizeof(function) makes sense?**

Stated in the document under section  [8.5.2.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1)/ *(draft N3337, page 105, sec. **5.3.3**)*:

> 1. The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>      *function* or *incomplete type*, to an *enumeration type* whose underlying
>      type is not fixed before all its enumerators have been declared, to
>      the *parenthesized name* of such types, or to an *lvalue* that
>      designates a bit-field.
> 2. The sizeof operator can be applied to a *pointer to a function*, but
>      shall not be applied directly to a *function*.
> 3. The *lvalue-to-rvalue* , *array-to-pointer* , and *function-to-pointer*  standard conversions are not applied to the operand of `sizeof`.
> 4. `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)`
>      are 1. The result of sizeof applied to any other [fundamental type
>      (3.9.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental) is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Although `sizeof(func)` is invalid as rightly pointed out in Avi Weiss and JeJo's answers, you will not necessarily get an error if you try it.

In GNU C, `sizeof(void)` and `sizeof(func)` are allowed as an extension and evaluate to 1. [This is a documented extension.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) As required by the standard, you will get a warning for it, but not an error. This extension is also available in C++ mode.